# How to count number of assignments in Julia?

Tags: julia

I know that Julia has a @time macro that outputs the amount of memory that is allocated, but is there any way to measure the number of assignments made in a function?

Comment: this macro also prints the number of allocations.

Comment: `@timev` will printout more information about number of allocations and their type.

Comment: @RezaAfzalan +1 for `@timev` thanks for pointing me to it! There is also `@timed` which returns the timing, etc. info in a tuple for further analysis.

Comment: That's a very useful macro, but not quite what I was looking for. I was wondering if there was a way to track *assignments*, not allocations. Assignments are when a variable is set to a value. Something can be allocated once, but assigned to many times.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is counting *assignments* is that by the time the machine runs the code, register or memory loads and stores no longer correspond to the assignments of the original code. For instance, the code

```
julia> g(x) = x^3
g (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_llvm g(1)

define i64 @julia_g_70778(i64) #0 {
top:
  %1 = mul i64 %0, %0
  %2 = mul i64 %1, %0
  ret i64 %2
}

julia> @code_native g(1)
    .text
Filename: REPL[7]
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Source line: 1
    movq    %rdi, %rax
    imulq   %rax, %rax
    imulq   %rdi, %rax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    nopw    %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

clearly has four "assignments", two `movq` and two `imulq`. But the original code did not have a single assignment.

The closest you can get, therefore, is to use a macro to rewrite assignments so that they increment a counter (in addition to actually doing the assigning). This will of course likely slow down your code substantially, so I do not recommend it.